# how to store a redux state that contain data from express cookie so when we reload page the state still there and not reset?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, cookies

#### Issue with Persisting User Login Sessions in Express.js and React

I'm encountering an issue with persisting user login sessions in my Express.js and React application. Here's a brief overview of the problem and the relevant code snippets:

##### Problem:

After successfully logging in, the user's authentication state is stored in Redux state (`isAuthenticated: true`). However, upon reloading the page, the user is required to log in again.

##### Code Snippets:

1. **Express.js Route for Login:**

```js
const { email, password } = req.body;
try {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (user) {
    // Logic here
    // Send cookie with user token
    sendCookie(user, 200, res);
    return; // Return after sending the response
  }
}
```

2. **Function to Send Cookie:**

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const sendCookie = (user = {}, statusCode, res) => {
  const expiresInSeconds = parseInt(process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE) * 24 * 60 * 60;

  // Sign the token using the user object
  const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: expiresInSeconds,
  });

  const options = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'None',
  };

  res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options).json({
    success: true,
    user,
  });
};

module.exports = sendCookie;
```

3. **Redux Reducer:**

```js
case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    isAuthenticated: true,
    user: action.payload,
    error: null,
  };
```

##### Additional Information:

I attempted to store the cookie in the browser's cookie storage and access it upon reload to set `isLoggedIn` to `true`. However, when I deployed the app on Vercel, I couldn't access the cookie from the cookie storage. It seems that the cookie is only sent in the network panel, even though I've set `httpOnly` to `false`. I suspect that Vercel might be hiding the cookie to prevent XSS attacks.

##### Request:

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and ensure that user login sessions persist across reloads in my application. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use redux-persist package it will persist your data in the browser